Python dictionaries are different during processing and after
What I'm trying to do is split a list of dictionaries if a field has n values separated by commas, into a list of n dictionaries where all other fields are same but the field with multiple values now has unique values.
Here's the output:
 before
[{'id': 1, 'time': '1,2,3'}, {'id': 2, 'time': '4,5'}, {'id': 3, 'time': '6'}, {'id': 4, 'time': '7,8,9,10'}]
during
['1', '2', '3']
{'id': 1, 'time': '1'}
{'id': 1, 'time': '2'}
{'id': 1, 'time': '3'}
['4', '5']
{'id': 2, 'time': '4'}
{'id': 2, 'time': '5'}
['7', '8', '9', '10']
{'id': 4, 'time': '7'}
{'id': 4, 'time': '8'}
{'id': 4, 'time': '9'}
{'id': 4, 'time': '10'}
after
{'id': 1, 'time': '3'}
{'id': 2, 'time': '5'}
{'id': 3, 'time': '6'}
{'id': 4, 'time': '10'}
{'id': 1, 'time': '3'}
{'id': 1, 'time': '3'}
{'id': 2, 'time': '5'}
{'id': 4, 'time': '10'}
{'id': 4, 'time': '10'}
{'id': 4, 'time': '10'}

Why is this happening?
How can I make the code better?
Thanks in advance.
Here's my code
meta = [{"id":1,"time":"1,2,3"},{"id":2,"time":"4,5"},{"id":3,"time":"6"},{"id":4,"time":"7,8,9,10"}]
print("before")
print(meta)
meta_copy = meta.copy()
placeholder = meta.copy()

print("during")
for i in range(len(meta)):
    if "," in meta[i]["time"]:
        sub = meta[i]["time"].split(",")
        print(sub)
        for j in range(len(sub)):
            if j == 0:

                meta_copy[i]["time"] = sub[0]
                print(meta_copy[i])
            else:
                placeholder[i]["time"]=sub[j]
                #print(placeholder[i]["time"])
                meta_copy.append(placeholder[i])
                print( meta_copy[-1])
print("after")
for l in range(len(meta_copy)):
    print(meta_copy[l])


The copy method of a list only makes a shallow copy. This means that the dictionaries in original and copy are the very same, not copies of each other. You should use the clone method of dicts to create (shallow) copies of them where needed.

In Python dictionaries are mutable. When you do placeholder = meta.copy() you are creating a copy. Since the object in placeholder is the same as in meta when you modify placeholder[i] you are also modifying the same dictionary in meta_copy.
You need to create a deep copy before modifying it. Use deepcopy module from copy:
import copy
meta = [{"id":1,"time":"1,2,3"},{"id":2,"time":"4,5"},{"id":3,"time":"6"},{"id":4,"time":"7,8,9,10"}]
print("before")
print(meta)
meta_copy = meta.copy()
print("during")
for i in range(len(meta)):
    if "," in meta[i]["time"]:
        sub = meta[i]["time"].split(",")
        print(sub)
        for j in range(len(sub)):
            if j == 0:
                meta_copy[i]["time"] = sub[0]
                print(meta_copy[i])
            else:
                placeholder = copy.deepcopy(meta_copy[i])
                placeholder["time"]=sub[j]
                meta_copy.append(placeholder)
                print(meta_copy[-1])
print("after")
for l in range (len(meta_copy)):
    print(meta_copy[l])

